# Why does the rule defining the term for a constant expression have to be so cluttered?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I do not understand why a temporary object, which is referred to by a prvalue core constant expression, must not have any pointer or a reference, which points or refers to an object with storage duration other than static, in order for that prvalue core constant expression to be a constant expression; see **N4296 [expr.const] 5.20\5**.

I think it is possible for implementations to rewrite that rule like this:

**[expr.const] 5.20\5 (modified)**

> A core constant expression e is a *constant expression*, unless it
>   initializes an object such that it contains a pointer, which points to
>   an object with storage duration other than static.

If it is not, can someone, please, explain why?

Comment: Your version would allow a pointer to an object with static storage duration, that in turn contains a pointer to an object with dynamic storage duration. Your version would also disallow null pointers.

Comment: @RaymondChen Hmm... But doesn't a null pointer value point to no object at all? And I do not understand why a pointer to an object with dynamic storage duration would be a problem in your example. Please, explain.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to rephrase the definition to be equivalent to the old definition, but simpler. But instead, it sounds like you want to change the definition itself.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yeah, it was and it still is a mess... But I think about your example of null pointer values and such. Interesting...

Comment: @RaymondChen Mwahaha. You are right. I made a mistake. There will be problems in the rule proposed by me, because subobjects of a non-volatile object defined with 'constexpr' need not to be initialized by a constant expression (7.1.5\4.5, 9) and, moreover, the 'operator &' does not invoke lvalue-to-prvalue conversion, so such unary expression would be allowed in any pointer arithmetic subexpression of a constant expression, therefore it would not be possible to calculate it at compile-time.

Comment: So, I have rewritten my proposition. The question is still there. If I am right, the Standard has a similar problem: you can get a pointer of an object with, say, local storage duration through operator & (not an lvalue-to-prvalue conversion) and then use it in a pointer arithmetic to obtain some integral prvalue, which depends on run-time.

Comment: The number of people who understand all the nuances in this area can probably be counted with one hand. Have you tried asking Richard Smith?

Comment: @T.C. No, I haven't. It would be nice, if someone asked him and we resolved the issue. Can you do it?

Comment: Excuse me, there is no such problem in the Standard. You cannot get a  result for a pointer arithmetic in a constant expression, which depends on run-time. Because the rule 5.20\2.9.1 in the Standard does not allow to get two lvalue expressions, which refer to two elements of an array with indices, which depend on run-time. And any other pointer arithmetic has undefined behavior...

Comment: @RaymondChen So, it seems, my first proposition is right too. I actually made a mistake claiming to you, that subobjects of the constexpr object need not to be initialized by a constant expressions. Reading 7.1.5\4.5, 9, I should have paid more attention to the clause regarding the initialization of a constexpr object by a constructor call. All member initializations are part of the evaluation (5.20\2) of that call.

Comment: You should probably specify which version of the standard you refer to, or quote the original wording. In the version I have here there's no 5.20.

Comment: Voted as "unclear" because you've made this question a moving target, that people can't even reasonably comment on, let alone answer definitively.  Edits to questions are meant to allow clarification, not to change what is being asked about.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I tried to clarify the question by providing a reasonable alternative to the rule. Excuse me, it was not so easy for me. Anyway the current revision is almost the same as the first.

Comment: Umm. It does seem, we can reasonably write the rule like just this: **[expr.const] 5.20\5 (modified)** "A core constant expression is a _constant_ _expression_ and vice versa."

Answer (score 1):

> which points to an object with storage duration other than static

1. You ruled out null-pointers
2. You ruled out function-pointers

From standard 5.20\5:

> (5.2) if the object or subobject is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past the end of such an object (5.7), the address of a function, or a null pointer value

3. You omitted notion of references as members in objects. What to do with them? You can take const reference of runtime object or static object. Does this make whole object to be `core constant expression` or not?

> (5.1) each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression

I bet there is an additional nuance with `glvalue core constant expression` and `prvalue core constant expression` ( as I understand this phrase excludes some of `xvalue` ), but I fail to grasp it. I hope that someone will explain this.

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression whose value refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose
>   value is an object

**EDIT**

> So what is a problem with that? There are still other rules, you know:
>   5.20\2.7, 2.9, 2.13, 2.19, 2.5; etc. ; )

Yes, **5.20/2.9** is about references ( other mentioned rules doesn't apply to reference types - as I understand them ). Let's read it.

> (2) A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless
>   the evaluation of e , following the rules of the abstract machine (
>   1.9 ), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>   (2.9) an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of
>   reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and
>   either
>   — (2.9.1) it is initialized with a constant expression or
>   — (2.9.2) it is a non-static data member of an object whose lifetime
>   began within the evaluation of e ;

Now let's compare your rule and standard's. Standard adds some details to **5.20/2.9**.

> **5.20/5**
>   (5.1) each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression
>   An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an object with static storage duration that is either not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints, or it is a function.

- again we see mention of `functions` ( like with pointers ) - your rule (based on **5.20/2.9** ) lacks it.
- there is no mention of reference to `object with static storage duration` in your rule

Comment: Yes, I did do it. I (almost) annihilated the rule : D ...Now member references in a constant expression may be initialized to refer to objects with storage duration other than static, yes. So what is a problem with that? There are still other rules, you know: **5.20\2.7, 2.9, 2.13, 2.19, 2.5**; etc. ; )

Comment: Yes, there may be pointers to functions in an object initialized by a constant expression according to my proposition. It is not a problem. Functions are good actually : ) Their addresses are known at compile-time, are they not?

Comment: I've mentioned two differences in my edit: references to functions ( I've remembered pointers to functions too, but they weren't main point ) and references to object with static storage duration. Your rule lacks them.

Comment: References do not make problems, so they are not mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean by problems? Those two cases weren't mentioned in earlier rules before **5.20/5**, in your version they just doesn't exist for const expression. That's the difference - standard must include all possible variants, they can't omit anything just because it's obvious for someone.